Gradle update in flutter
 [!] Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.                            
 Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update 
 C:\Users\MR_KABUTEYY\Desktop\Flutter\smoke_detector\android\build.gradle:                         
 ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>'  

i tried to download the new gradle version but still didn't work out

Add ext.kotlin_version = '<latest-version>' (add the latest version) at build.gradle and change the current Kotlin version in the gradle.properties file as well. Make sure to check that the minsdk version is above 21 and the complied SDK version is 33.

Just open your android dir in Android Studio, it will analyse it and recommend you the upgrade.

Add the Kotlin version in android/settings.gradle inside plugins:
plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.3.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "{kotlinVersion}" apply false //Kotlin Version
}

You can find latest Kotlin version from Kotlin releases.
Your problem will be solved. In case if you still getting this error then add ext.kotlin_version in android/build.gradle:
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '{KotlinVersion}' //Latest Kotlin version
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

